# Android format edittext to display spaces after every character is inputted

Tags: android, android-edittext

Android - I want to enter numeric input from the user into the EditText - and I press KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER then it must be separated by a space - every character is inputted, but the maximum space is only 14.

Example:

1234 -> 1234 (add 10 space)

123456 -> 123456 (add 8 spaces)

This is only for exporting my data

What's the easiest way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your String to a `StringBuilder` and then add spaces from the last character (string.length()) until 14:

```
StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder(editText.getText().toString());

for (int i = txt.length(); i < 14; i++)
     txt.append(" ");
```